# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '12/08/2015' to data type int

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get these comma separated dates and all i get is this error I'd tried all other conversion stuff but nothing good appears to be happened

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000)= '12/08/2015,12/07/2015,12/10/2015,12/06/2015,12/09/2015'
Declare @x XML 
select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(@str,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml)

select t.value('.', 'int') as inVal
from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)
```

I tried other stuff too but when i try to bind it with datatable null value returns

Comment: I already tried CAST nothing good happened

Comment: Whaaa, what are you doing? Best to elaborate, tell us what the expected output is for the delimited string of dates.

Comment: Like this as numbers appeared http://prntscr.com/9axfs4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`12/08/2015` is not valid `INT`. Convert to `DATE` instead:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000)= '12/08/2015,12/07/2015,12/10/2015,12/06/2015,12/09/2015'
Declare @x XML 
select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(@str,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml)

select t.value('.', 'date') as inVal
from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404181)**</kbd>

If you want all `INT` replace `/` with `,`:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(4000)= '12/08/2015,12/07/2015,12/10/2015,12/06/2015,12/09/2015'
Declare @x XML 
select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(REPLACE(@str, '/',','),',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml)

select t.value('.', 'INT') as inVal
from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404189)**</kbd>

Comment: How did you do the SQL live demo? I haven't seen that yet?

Comment: @JeremyThompson This is SEDE (StackExchange Data Explorer). Write query, run it and click pernament link. You can easily write quries that uses temp table/table variables but you can't create normal tables.

Comment: awesome +1 just for that tip, for everyone else here it is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/how-can-i-insert-a-sql-live-demo-into-my-answer/311053#311053

Comment: Thanks mate it was very helpful

Comment: @lad2025 date appears in 2015-12-08  can i've the same format of date as above

Comment: @user3515453 Sorry I am not sure I understand your last comment. Can you elaborate what you want to achieve with `2015-12-08`?

Comment: @lad2025 The date format should be 12/08/2015 instead of 2015-12-08

Comment: I tried to convert it by using format 101 It won't work

Comment: @user3515453 Data is stored as date type. This is only presentation matter: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404222

Comment: Thanks love that was very helpful :)